# How to display map when i call screen

Tags: flutter

I have been using map_view: ^0.0.14 plugin to display map in flutter. Mapview.show() method does not return widget. It returns void So i can call show() method and display map. I want to display map When page loads. How can i do that.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Google Maps'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Tap me'),
            color: Colors.blue,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 7.0,
            onPressed: ( ) {
              mapView.show(
                  new MapOptions(
                      mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
                      showMyLocationButton: true,
                      showCompassButton: true,
                      showUserLocation: true,
                      initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(new Location(11.6643, 78.1460), 14.0),
                      title: 'Google Map'));
          },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell map_view doesn't have a widget.
You can give [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter) a try, which has a widget that let's you do things like pan or zoom through a controller.

---

You'll first need to specify your API key in your app's manifest (Android):

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="YOUR KEY HERE"/>
```

or the app delegate (iOS):

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
@end
```

On iOS you'll also have to add a boolean to your `Info.plist` with the key `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` and the value `YES`.

Then you can add the GoogleMap widget to your widget tree:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Google Maps demo')),
      body: MapsDemo(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {

  GoogleMapController mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 300.0,
              height: 200.0,
              child: GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('Go to London'),
            onPressed: mapController == null ? null : () {
              mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                const CameraPosition(
                  bearing: 270.0,
                  target: LatLng(51.5160895, -0.1294527),
                  tilt: 30.0,
                  zoom: 17.0,
                ),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() { mapController = controller; });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some more detail or a documentation for your answer?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the documentation provided in the package's README.

Comment: Thanks you. It's working fine but I want to capture marker event.